# Coffee Texture as not Expected

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders, blend-files

Supposed done all things right, but it still showing some weird things on Coffee Part, What is the problem ?
Thanks in advance!
[image: Still something missing.][image: This one, is my target]Supposed done all things right, but it still showing some weird things on Coffee Part, What is the problem ?
[image: Rendered result][image: Shading Details]

Comment: what's your target? do you have an image as reference?

Comment: I want like this one, https://imgur.com/a/kf9UY7S

Comment: You're missing the subsurface scattering.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Increase Subsurface value to 0.3. still something missing. Am I need to add SSS node? then where ?